# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||' in dynamic query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have problem with construction dynamic query.

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 10, column 25:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'
ORA-06550: line 10, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 16, column 17:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'
ORA-06550: line 16, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:


declare
  v_column_order View_Columns.Column_order%TYPE;

   column_order_sql_qry     VARCHAR2 (150);
   insert_query    Varchar2(300);
  CURSOR view_ids IS select view_id from Views where template_name in ('mydhli_containers', 'demo_mydhli_containers', 'mydhli_shipments', 'demo_mydhli_shipments', 'mydhli_shipments_gogreen', 'demo_mydhli_shipments_gogreen');
begin

FOR v_view_id IN view_ids LOOP
column_order_sql_qry := 'select max(column_order)  from view_columns vc inner join views vi on vc.view_id = vi.view_id where vc.view_id = ' || v_view_id;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE column_order_sql_qry into v_column_order;

v_column_order := v_column_order + 1;

insert_query := 'insert into VIEW_COLUMNS(ID, COLUMN_ORDER, NAME, VIEW_ID) VALUES (view_column_id_seq.nextval, ' || v_column_order || ',''commercialInvoiceNumbers'',' || v_view_id || ')';


EXECUTE IMMEDIATE insert_query;

END LOOP;

end;
```

I dont know if I should cast number parameters to char or what to do. It seems that nocmal concatination with || doesnt working.Thanks for help

Comment: [13.17 Cursor FOR LOOP Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/cursor-FOR-LOOP-statement.html#GUID-62C9A3C8-82F9-468F-8D84-81672E67736D): ***record**: Name for the loop index that the cursor FOR LOOP statement implicitly declares as a `%ROWTYPE` record variable of the type that `cursor` or `select_statement` returns.* Oracle has no implicit to string type cast for record variable. Use `v_view_id.view_id` in concatenation

Comment: But view id isnt recore type, Its variable with type number inherited it from column

Comment: @PaulW - the column returned by the cursor for-loop is named `VIEW_ID`.

Comment: @PetrKostroun As of syntax rules for PL/SQL (see linked article): `v_view_id` **is** a record of one attribute of type number. This is not the same as a plain number type.

Comment: @Bob thanks, I misread the column_order_sql_qry as the cursor sql

Comment: @PaulW - yeah, no worries, it's early (at least here :-)

Answer (score 0):

`v_view_id` is a row variable. You need to specify which field out of those returned by the cursor you want to use. So something like

```
column_order_sql_qry := 'select max(column_order)  from view_columns vc inner join views vi on vc.view_id = vi.view_id where vc.view_id = ' || v_view_id.view_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your tables so I created dummy ones, just to make code compile.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE views
  2  AS
  3     SELECT 'mydhli_containers' template_name, 1 view_id FROM DUAL;

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE view_columns
  2  AS
  3     SELECT 1 view_id, 2 column_order FROM DUAL;

Table created.

SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
```

Cursor `FOR` loop:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_column_order        View_Columns.Column_order%TYPE;
  3
  4     column_order_sql_qry  VARCHAR2 (150);
  5     insert_query          VARCHAR2 (300);
  6  BEGIN
  7     FOR cur_r in (
  8        SELECT view_id
  9          FROM Views
 10         WHERE template_name IN ('mydhli_containers',
 11                                 'demo_mydhli_containers',
 12                                 'mydhli_shipments',
 13                                 'demo_mydhli_shipments',
 14                                 'mydhli_shipments_gogreen',
 15                                 'demo_mydhli_shipments_gogreen'))
 16     LOOP
 17        column_order_sql_qry :=
 18              'select max(column_order)  from view_columns vc inner join views vi on vc.view_id = vi.view_id where vc.view_id = '
 19           || cur_r.view_id;
 20
 21        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE column_order_sql_qry
 22           INTO v_column_order;
 23
 24        v_column_order := v_column_order + 1;
 25
 26        insert_query :=
 27              'insert into VIEW_COLUMNS(ID, COLUMN_ORDER, NAME, VIEW_ID) VALUES (view_column_id_seq.nextval, '
 28           || v_column_order
 29           || ',''commercialInvoiceNumbers'','
 30           || cur_r.view_id
 31           || ')';
 32
 33        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (insert_query);
 34        -- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE insert_query;
 35     END LOOP;
 36  END;
 37  /
```

Result:

```
insert into VIEW_COLUMNS(ID, COLUMN_ORDER, NAME, VIEW_ID) VALUES
(view_column_id_seq.nextval, 3,'commercialInvoiceNumbers',1)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```